# Put the bar of the scroll bar on the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a css attribute or sort of thing that puts the bar of a scroll bar on the bottom, euh, a div with fix height and width, shows a text, but the text is too big and wrapped into this div, so a scroll bar appears but the bar is in the top, I want it to appears on the bottom, did you understand me? if so, please just say how.

Regards.

Comment: What sort of moon software are you using where horizontal scrollbars show up at the *top* of the scrolling region?

Comment: @Pointy, please, I did not understand you.

Comment: @Pointy: I think he's talking about a vertical scrollbar, and he'd like it to be scrolled to the end.

Comment: @Pointy, exactly, sorry if I could not send you my issue, so now how?

Comment: @Frits van Compen, yes, what do you suggest, I saw em use it in the chat box, when you enter your message the list'll appears and the scrollbar go to bottom to show the latest messages, u got it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use Javascript, I found this handy little snippet: http://radio.javaranch.com/pascarello/2005/12/14/1134573598403.html So, you'd have a div object somewhere on your page and have it call your scroll to bottom function onload:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script>
            function scroll_to_bottom(){
                var objDiv = document.getElementById("divExample");
                objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
            }
        </script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <div id="divExample" onload="scroll_to_bottom();"></div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I'm not sure if that is browser specific or not, but give it a shot and see what happens. Let me know if it works or if you have problems.

UPDATE: It looks like all browsers support scrollTop, and all but the earlier versions of IE support scrollHeight. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#elementview

Comment: Pretty much... More people should google before asking questions here. It might save em some time.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I been looking for!